# How to remove words after my needed for me words

Tags: python, discord.py

How to remove all not neded words after one needed for me word

What i'm have:

````
 if "\"message\":\"Logged in!\"" in response1.text:
  response_time = response1.text[response1.text.find("expiry") + 9 : ]
  #datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(response_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') dont look to this, that not works before i'm not remove not needed words from response content.
  print(f"\n\n{response_time}\n\n")
  embed = discord.Embed(
  description=f"You are successfully logged in!\n\n```Information: {username}{response_time}", colour=COLOR)
  await msg.channel.send(embed=embed, delete_after=150)
  return
````

How it looks when i'm not cut not needed content:

```
{"success":true,"message":"Logged in!","info":{"username":"DeadFinder","subscriptions":[{"subscription":"default","expiry":"1635683460"}],"ip":"some not static numbers"}}
```

I'm need to cut all after my timestamp, at this moment i cutted all before my timestamp

```
1635683460"}],"ip":"some not static numbers"}} #that how it looks after code completes
```

I'm need only *1635683460*, this numbers is not static, i cant just use code to find this numbers and replace all after that

Comment: Why don’t you just iterate over the dictionary object and get the value for the time stamp? You will of course have to `json.loads` It first, from the looks of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using [python requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)? If so, use `response1.json()` instead to get a dict object (and read below).

If not, use `json.loads(response1.text)` to get a dict object (see [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads))

From this [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), you can do `data["info"]["subscriptions"][0]["expiry"]`